# Simple boolean on/off button in Processing

Tags: button, boolean, processing

I'm trying to write button class, one that would switch between on and off states using boolean function.

Switch should happen after if(mousePressed). I can get it to work one way, but I'm lost while trying to get it to switch back to previous state.

When I change one of the if(mousePressed) to if(keyPressed) everything works just fine.

Thank you for your time good Sir.

```
  bclass button;
  int offset = 20;

void setup() {
  rectMode(CORNERS);
  noStroke();
  size(300, 100);

  button = new bclass(offset, offset, width-offset, height-offset);

}


void draw() {
  button.display();
  button.state(mouseX, mouseY);

}


class bclass {
  float x;
  float y;
  float w;
  float h;
  boolean state = false;



  bclass(float x_, float y_, float w_, float h_) {
    x = x_;
    y = y_;
    w = w_;
    h = h_;
  }

  void display() {

    if (state) {
       fill(255, 0, 0);
    } else {
      fill(0);
    }

    rect(x, y, w, h);

  }

  void state(int mx, int my) {

    if (!state) {
      if (mousePressed) {
        if (mx > x && mx < x + w) {
          state = true;
        }
      }
    }

    if (state) {   
      if (mousePressed) {
        if (mx > x && mx < x + w) {
          state = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the behavior you're actually observing? Is the state just not switching back or are you getting errors?

Comment: What I get is that void state function locks itself. Program defaultly starts with button being "off" (boolean is false). Program runs all right, but when I press the button nothing happens, as if program can't decide which way to go, whether to follow first condition if(!state) or second if(state).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your state method to:

```
void state(int mx, int my) {

    if (mousePressed) {
        if (mx > x && mx < x + w) {
            state = !state;         // change state to opposite value
            delay(100);             // delay 100ms (mousePressed lasts some millis)
        }
    }

}
```

But better solution will be to use Processing's `mouseClicked()` event:

```
public void draw() {
    button.display();
}

public void mouseClicked() {
    button.state(mouseX, mouseY);
}

class bclass {
    ...
    void state(int mx, int my) {

            if (mx > x && mx < x + w) {
                state = !state;
            }
    }
}
```

In this solution `button.state()` is called only from `mouseClicked()`, and `mouseClicked()` is called by Processing when it discovers such event.